# Getting the Latitude and Longitude for areas outside the U.S

Tags: php, google-maps, geocoding

Can the API for Google Maps be used to retrieve the latitude and longitude for a given Postal Code or City+Region combination for foreign countries such as The United Kingdon, France, Italy, Japan, Australia etc. ?

I am working on a project that requires local search results. For domestic users I retrieve their lat/lon via a U.S Zip Codes Table in our database. It does not involve showing any maps, just results of other users who are in their area via a radius formula based on lat/lon values. For foreign users' local search results: I am just showing results based on matching City Name.

At the moment non-U.S users lat/lon is being retrieved via PHP GeoIP data. I'd like to be able to retrieve more accurate values depending on the city+region or postal code the user provides.

I am considering getting postal code tables (which have lat/lon fields) for other countries. Or is the Google Map API idea a better solution?

Comment: Hm.. I just noticed this http://www.maxmind.com/app/worldcities which doesn't include postal codes but at least it gives lat/lon for given city names.

Comment: Whether those countries are "foreign" or not depends on your point of view, of course.

Comment: I edited the title of my question. The downside to not having postal code data is that every user from a given city will have the same lat/lon coordinates, so showing results from nearest to furthest won't be possible, however, users from neighboring cities can be included. This is still a step up from what I am currently doing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have found the results from the [Google Maps Geocoder](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/reference.html#GClientGeocoder) to be pretty good.

To test out your foreign postcodes or addresses (without writing any code), just attach the country name to the string and try it out in the [google maps](http://maps.google.com/) search box.

Or, you can implement the lookup pretty quickly in Javascript:

```
geo = new GClientGeocoder ();
geo.getLatLng("2337, Australia", function (point) {
        GLog.write(point.lat() + "," point.lng());
    });
```

Comment: This seems like the best step forward. Heading out for a late dinner and then I'll give this a go. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I've previously used Google Maps for its geocoding, works well and can work for anywhere in the world.

Use the GClientGeocoder from google and use the 'setBaseCountryCode(countryCode:String)' method to set it to the countries top-level domain (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CcTLD)

Answer (score 0):

Mapping from Postal codes to lat/lon pairs: [GeoNames Postal Code Database](http://download.geonames.org/export/zip/)

Also available as a [GeoNames webservice](http://www.geonames.org/export/)...